# C# Form doesn't show input

Tags: c#, forms

I want to build in C# a form, which has as input a day, month and year.

This is what I have so far, the form works, but the input isn't showed on the next page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
     public class VerwerkController : Controller
     {
        // GET: Verwerk
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
             return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Verwerk(int dag, String maand, int jaar)
        {
            int day = dag;
            String month = maand;
            int year = jaar;

            return View(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
        }
    }
}
```

This is VerwerkController.cs and the code below is Index.cshtml (View).

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <form name="input" action="/home/verwerk" method="post" >
            Dag: <input type="number" name="dag" /><br />            
            Maand: <input type="text" name="maand" /><br />
            Jaar: <input type="number" name="jaar" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="send" /><br />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just started with C# and I don't get this working, anyone a solution?

I got the following 4 files now:

VerwerkModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class VerwerkModel
    {
        public int Dag { get; set; }
        public string Maand { get; set; }
        public int Jaar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Verwerk.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Model WebApplication3.Models.VerwerkModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Verwerk</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>@Model.Dag</div>
    <div>@Model.Maand</div>
    <div>@Model.Jaar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

VerwerkController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class VerwerkController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Verwerk
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Verwerk(int dag, String maand, int jaar)
        {
            var model = new VerwerkModel
            {
                Dag = dag,
                Maand = maand,
                Jaar = jaar,
            };

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <form name="input" action="/Home/Verwerk" method="get" >
            Dag: <input type="number" name="dag" /><br />            
            Maand: <input type="text" name="maand" /><br />
            Jaar: <input type="number" name="jaar" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="send" /><br />
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the error comes when I press the send button.

> De bron kan niet worden gevonden. (Source can't be found)
>
> Beschrijving(Description): HTTP 404. Mogelijk is de door u gezochte bron (of een >afhankelijkheid daarvan) verwijderd of tijdelijk niet beschikbaar, of is de >naam ervan veranderd. Controleer de spelling van de volgende URL. (It is possible that the source, where is searched for, is deleted or temporarily unavailable or it's name has changed. Check the following URL for mistypes.)
>
> Aangevraagde(Requested) URL: /Home/Verwerk

Another error:

```
>The view 'verwerk' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the >searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>~/Views/verwerk/verwerk.aspx
>~/Views/verwerk/verwerk.ascx
>~/Views/Shared/verwerk.aspx
>~/Views/Shared/verwerk.ascx
>~/Views/verwerk/verwerk.cshtml
>~/Views/verwerk/verwerk.vbhtml
>~/Views/Shared/verwerk.cshtml
>~/Views/Shared/verwerk.vbhtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you seem to returning a non-existent view:

```
return View(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
```

I guess that you don't have a view named `07/03/2015.cshtml` which is what you are attempting to render here. Instead you might consider rendering some existing view and passing the correct model. For example assuming that you have defined a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Dag { get; set; } 
    public string Maand { get; set; } 
    public int Jaar { get; set; }
}
```

and a corresponding view `Verwerk.cshtml`:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>@Model.Dag</div>
<div>@Model.Maand</div>
<div>@Model.Jaar</div>
```

you could render this view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Verwerk(int dag, String maand, int jaar)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Dag = dag,
        Maand = maand,
        Jaar = jaar,
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

or if you want to render a particular view like `FooBar.cshtml` you could use:

```
return View("FooBar", model);
```

Also your form action is wrong:

```
<form name="input" action="/home/verwerk" method="post">
```

It should be:

```
<form name="input" action="/verwerk/verwerk" method="post">
```

because your `Verwerk` action seem to be defined inside a `VerwerkController` and not inside `HomeController`.

Comment: Where exactly do I define that new model?

Comment: Wherever you want. The `Models` folder might be a good place. It's just a regular view model represented by a standard C# class.

Comment: I created a separate model and edited all the things you said, but I still got the error on page: Source can't be found

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you did and the precise error you are getting.

Comment: OK, now it's clear that your form action is pointing to the wring url. It should be `action="/verwerk/verwerk"` instead of `action="/home/verwerk"` because your `Verwerk` action is defined inside `VerwerkController` and not inside `HomeController`. I have also updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yeah, Now I see, this was a practice excercise with an exemple that used the wrong URL, but now I got another error:        see head post

Comment: It works now, apparently I had place the Verwerk View in the Home map instead of the Verwerk map, I now get the following result: WebApplication3.Models.VerwerkModel WebApplication3.Models.VerwerkModel
3
Maart
2015  The day 3 month Maart and year 2015 are correct, but why is it also giving those first 2 rules?